# "Compute" type based on size in Julia

Tags: methods, types, julia

Let's say, for the sake of an example, that I have defined the following three methods which do essentially the same.  Is there a way to do this with one definition?  The padding can certainly be done with `sizeof`, but how can I "compute" the correct type to use for `reinterpret`?

```
function showFloat(x::Float64)
  i = reinterpret(UInt64,x)
  print("0x")
  print(string(i,base=16,pad=16))
  print(" 0b")
  print(string(i,base=2,pad=64))
end

function showFloat(x::Float32)
  i = reinterpret(UInt32,x)
  print("0x")
  print(string(i,base=16,pad=8))
  print(" 0b")
  print(string(i,base=2,pad=32))
end

function showFloat(x::Float16)
  i = reinterpret(UInt16,x)
  print("0x")
  print(string(i,base=16,pad=4))
  print(" 0b")
  print(string(i,base=2,pad=16))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that this is what you need:

```
findtype(T) = first(filter!(U->sizeof(U)==sizeof(T), subtypes(Unsigned)))
```

And now:

```
julia> findtype.([Float16, Float32, Float64])
3-element Vector{DataType}:
 UInt16
 UInt32
 UInt64
```